# How to change the Default APK installation Path when using Flavors in Flutter VSCode?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am using flavors in vscode for `uat` and `production`.

So, when I am using `uat` then my apk is built properly and I can see the following message in debug console `Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-uat-debug.apk.`.

But, in debug console, I can see that the APK which is being installed is different with the following message `Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...`

**So, How I can configure vscode to install the `app-uat-debug.apk` instead of `app.apk` ?**

Answer (score 1):

***You have to make your*** `launch.json` ***like below*** :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dev",
            "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev",
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Staging",
            "program": "lib/main_stage.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "staging"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "UAT",
            "program": "lib/main_uat.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "uat"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Prod",
            "program": "lib/main_prod.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "prod"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

***into*** `android -> build.gradle`

```
 flavorDimensions "default"
     productFlavors {
        dev {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "dev"
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        staging {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "stages"
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        uat {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "uat" 
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
        }
        prod {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "app"
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
```

***To generate apk run the command into terminal***

```
flutter build apk --release -t ./lib/main_staging.dart --flavor stage
```

After that you will be get

[image]

Comment: I have already done these setup, but when I run the app then it shows `Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk` instead of `Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-uat-debug.apk`.

Comment: You have to generate apk

Comment: Then let me know my solun is working or not

Comment: In your device apk file is installing universal so got a message like Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk this but universal apk has flavour of app

Comment: Ok, I will check this in details, then I will update this thread.

Comment: I had setup flavors but when I run the app that time I found that it installs the right APK in my mobile but message shown in the VSCode seems to be misleading. I am not sure it is the bug in VS code or what? Because, when I run the `uat` version then it install this APK `build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-uat-debug.apk`, but the message shown in the bottom right corner of corner of VS code is like this `Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...`

Comment: @Israr yes because if you run your app flutter is running flavoring but it install as universal application, that is not an issue